# AngularJS ng-switch before load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I have an AngularJS template that looks like this:

```
<table data-ng-switch data-on="data.length">
    <tbody data-ng-switch-when="0">
        <tr>
            <td>No data available.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-ng-switch-default>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My controller and factory look like this:

```
demo.factory('Demo', function($resource) {
    return $resource('data.json');
});

demo.controller('DemoController', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Demo', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, Demo) {   
    $scope.data = Demo.query();
}]);
```

Is there a way to prevent "No data available." from flashing on the screen quickly before the data is retrieved from the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the $resource service returns an empty object that is asynchronously filled after the requested data is obtained.

To solve this:

1. Assign the requested data from a non $scope variable.
2. Create a function callback in the `query()` action.
3. Assign the non `$scope` variable in $scope.data within the function callback created in **step 2**.

e.g.

```
demo.controller('DemoController', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Demo', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, Demo) {   
    var queryData = Demo.query(function() {
      $scope.data = queryData;
    })
}]);
```

you may see other [examples in here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource).

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-cloak on the parent element.

```
<div ng-cloak>
    :: all the bindings that you want to wait for the bind to hapen
</div>
```

[AngularJS ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)